# 1980s or 90s story about inadvertent travel to alternate universes - and ritual urination

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, parallel-universe

I read this story in a digest magazine (Asimov's, F&SF or Amazing) in the 80s or 90s. The protagonist somehow starts to drift into increasingly unfamiliar alternative universes, where people act differently, dress differently or speak differently.  He struggles to fit in, but eventually is recognized as being unacceptably out of norm. After he is taken away by some sort of authority, his neighbors do something like ritually urinate on his driveway.

Comment: ", his neighbors do something like ritually urinate on his driveway" - The drunk guy three houses away from mine does that most Saturday nights

Comment: My sympathies...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Details](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42152) by Lawrence Person, from Asimov's April 1991.

**The protagonist somehow starts to drift into increasingly unfamiliar alternative universes, where people act differently, dress differently or speak differently.**

> It started with the coffee cups.
>
> Jason Wright was sitting at the breakfast table, looking through the
> Times, when Linda brought him his coffee. He brought the cup to his
> lips while reading the second page of the business section, then
> glanced  at it as he set it down on the table. After a moment, he
> glanced back  again.
>
> “Honey?”
>
> “Hum?”
>
> “Where’d you get the new cups.”
>
> “What new cups?”
>
> “These. The black ones.”
>
> Linda walked out of the kitchen and put the plate of eggs, bacon, and
> toasted bagel down in front of him. “They’re not new. They’re the same
> cups your mother gave us on our second anniversary.”

---

> What’s with the funny money?” Jason asked, still smiling.
>
> “What funny money, man? I gave you the ten I owed you, what’s the  big
> deal?”
>
> “Yeah, well tell me whose picture’s on here?”
>
> Ed looked at the bill.
>
> “Well, offhand I’d say it was Henry Clay. So?”
>
> “So? What do you mean, ‘so’?”
>
> “What I mean is, so what? You got problems with history or some-
> thing?”
>
> “C’mon, you know Hamilton’s on the ten dollar bill.”
>
> “Who? Look, man, I don’t know what you’re talking about. I gave you
> your money, so don’t get weird on me now.”

---

> Sunday. College, pro, high school, it didn’t matter. If it was
> football,  Jason watched it.
>
> And watched still as the field inexplicably narrowed and the team
> sizes  increased. He watched even when it become something resembling
> Aus-  tralian rules football, then a cross between soccer and field
> hockey, and  finally an incomprehensible game played with what
> appeared to be living  balls of fur and long, flexible cattle prods.
>
> And through all this, despite an ever-widening chasm between the two
> of them, Linda still loved him. Although she cried often, and the
> alien  words she spoke to him were all too frequently filled with
> sadness, she  stayed with him throughout it all, the only unchanging
> rock in the sea  of chaos his life had become.

**He struggles to fit in, but eventually is recognized as being unacceptably out of norm. After he is taken away by some sort of authority, his neighbors do something like ritually urinate on his driveway.**

> The police read Jason passages from the Koran as they locked the hoop
> and muzzle around him, then carried his unresisting body out to the
> hovercraft, where they dropped him unceremoniously into the rear hop-
> per. The Hallelujah chorus wailed through the top speakers as the
> engine  started up, the bright purple police light bouncing up and
> down in its  tube. **A few neighbors turned from where they had been
> decorating their  shrubbery with whalebones to watch Jason’s
> departure, shook their heads  sadly, then walked over to his house to
> urinate on his driveway**.
>
> From the window of his cell, Jason observed the last vestiges of his
> world disappear, watching as the sky turned yellow and great lumbering
> reptiles wandered across the red sanatorium lawn. At night, he stared
> at his reflection in the window, watching as his face slowly but
> surely  changed beyond all recognition.
>
> Finally, at long last, the doctors pronounced him cured.